# how to use HttpClient Async & Await to post FCM message

Tags: c#, firebase, http-headers, httpclient, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am struggling to use `HttpClient` to post FCM message. I am getting invalid  Header format exception.  I can use `WebRequest` to post FCM message. But I want to try as Async and Await by using HttpClient.

Please suggest me which is best HttpClient or WebRequest.

```
<div>
<br>String uri;
<br>uri = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

<br>var postData = new
<br>{
    <br>to = DeviceID,
<br>data = new
{
    MessageID = enquiryid
},<br>

<br>notification = new
{
    body = enquirymessage,
    title = FromUser,
    icon = "myicon"
}<br>
};<br>

<br>var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
<br>var json = serializer.Serialize(postData);<br>
<br>using (var client = new HttpClient())
<br>{
<p>client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new    AuthenticationHeaderValue

("key", "=" + fcmDetails.SERVER_API_KEY);<br>
<p>client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue

("application/json"));
<p>client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sender: id ", "="+ fcmDetails.PROJECT_KEY);

<p>using (var r =  client.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(uri), json))
<br>{
    <br>string result = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    <br>sResponseFromServer= result;

}<br>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line in your code

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sender: id ", "="+ fcmDetails.PROJECT_KEY);
```

with

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sender", "id=" + fcmDetails.PROJECT_KEY);

Use the sample code
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                      .Accept
                      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("key", "=" + fcmDetails.SERVER_API_KEY);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sender","id=" +  fcmDetails.PROJECT_KEY);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "relativeAddress");
                var data = new
                {
                    to = DeviceID,
                    notification = new
                    {
                        body = "This is the message",
                        title = "This is the title",
                        icon = "myicon"
                    }
                };

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
                request.Content = new StringContent(json,
                                                    Encoding.UTF8,
                                                    "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

                var data1 = client.PostAsync("send", request.Content);
                var d = data1.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am facing problem in BAD REQUEST in line 'using (var r = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(uri), json))'. Not sure its because of 'var json' value. But the code was working fine in **WebRequest**.

Comment: @PajaniArjunan Can you print the postData as String? See if the JSON structure is correct?

Comment: @PajaniArjunan i have added sample code check that and let me know if you require any more help